# Can I cast a column as TEXT in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table with 
CREATE TABLE AS SELECT .... ,'' AS COLUMN_X,... FROM TABLE A JOIN TABLE B ...

COLUMN_X is created with data type CHAR(0).
I want it as type TEXT.

How can I do that?

Is there any way to cast as TEXT in Mysql as in MS SQL Server

Comment: What is the datatype and value of column_x?

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your `COLOUMN_X` by this example for MySql:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

Learn [more](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

Comment: Yes. I did that. I want to know if there is any other way?